# Aspect based sentiment analysis using R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I want to find sentiments of aspect or entity in R. My first step is to get the dependency tree and find noun and adjective. **My question is how to find sentiment score of entity?**  Here i am using Udpipe library in R. Below is code i used to get dependency tree. I am not sure how to proceed further with the code:

```
ud_model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(ud_model$file_model)

text <- c("government is not good","Samsung is not as good as Nokia", "Stay was comfortable, price
           is very high, service is descent")  
y <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model, x = text, parallel.cores = 4)
y <- as.data.frame(y)
```

**Can you please help me with R code to find sentiment score of below entities?**

```
  Entities     Sentiments score
1.government          ???
2.Samsung             ???
3.Nokia               ???
4.Stay                ???
5.price               ???
6.service             ???
```

Thank you in advance for guiding me!!!

Comment: Note that asking for code is off topic on SO. To help you a bit further, names of companies don't tend to have sentiment attached to them. Sentiment analysis depends on the context of what you are trying to measure. Are you trying to measure the sentiment of the sentence? Or just words? A good start is [tidy text mining with R](https://www.tidytextmining.com/index.html) for examples. Other packages are SentimentAnalysis, sentimentr. But there are more all depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Kiwi, did you manage to build this?
If yes please share the code.

Comment: @phiver is there any unsupervised aspect based sentiment analysis solution in R?